# Could not resolve org.jetbrains:kotlin-css-jvm:1.0.0-pre.31-kotlin-1.2.41

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, ktor

I want to build a ktor based file and I got the compile error, but I don't have a clue what's wrong.

compile error:

Could not resolve `org.jetbrains:kotlin-css-jvm:1.0.0-pre.31-kotlin-1.2.41`

these are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version")

    testImplementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-tests:$ktor_version")
    implementation("org.jetbrains:kotlin-css-jvm:1.0.0-pre.31-kotlin-1.2.41")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-auth:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-gson:$ktor_version")
    implementation("org.litote.kmongo:kmongo:4.0.2")
    implementation("org.litote.kmongo:kmongo-coroutine:4.0.2")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7")
    implementation("commons-codec:commons-codec:1.14")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-network-tls:$ktor_version")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-freemarker:$ktor_version")

}
```

Comment: What's in your `repositories` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this worked for me

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url = uri("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/kotlin/p/kotlin/kotlin-js-wrappers/") }
}

dependencies {
       implementation ("org.jetbrains:kotlin-css-jvm:1.0.0-pre.31-kotlin-1.2.41")
}
```

https://mvnrepository.com/repos/space-kotlin-js-wrappers

Other releases
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers/kotlin-css?repo=space-kotlin-js-wrappers

Answer (score 3):

upgrading the version of css-jvm Solved the issue.

```
implementation "org.jetbrains:kotlin-css-jvm:1.0.0-pre.31-kotlin-1.2.41" to implementation "org.jetbrains:kotlin-css-jvm:1.0.0-pre.122-kotlin-1.4.10"
```

Answer (score 1):

This library is located in [kotlin-js-wrappers](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/kotlin-js-wrappers) repository. Make sure you have this repository added to your repositories list:

```kotlin
repositories {
    maven { url = uri("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-js-wrappers/") }
}
```

Also, note that modern version of this library has another artifact group and name ([`org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-css`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers/kotlin-css)), and is published in `mavenCentral()` repository.